# Consistency level of GlobalKTable

Tags: apache-kafka

What consistency level does a GlobalKTable have? I need strong consistency to ensure that values which contain a list are updated one at a time.

My guess is that it is at most eventually consistent, since the table is fully replicated for any number of partitions.

I just wanted to make sure, to justify extra effort required if its not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is built from a compacted topic. Consuming from this, or any topic, results in an eventually consistent model, yes.